# Why destructor is being called but construction not being called when passing object as a parameter?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

If I write a **class** named **Test** and write a **Test type** show() function like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{

public:
    int x;
    Test()
    {
        cout<<"Empty or Default Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    Test(int x)
    {
        cout<<"Valued constructor"<<endl;
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        cout<<"Destructor"<<x<<endl;
    }
    Test show(Test obj)
    {
        Test tt;
        tt.x=20;
        return tt;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test t1,t2(20);
    t2.show(t2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Empty or Default Constructor
Valued constructor
Empty or Default Constructor
Destructor : 20
Destructor : 1988276941
Destructor : 1988276941
Destructor : 1972875622
```

then output shows Destructor of **Test obj** and **return tt** but there is no constructor created for them but generally we know that firstly constructor will be created and after finishing the task destructor will be called but why is it exceptional while passing and returning any object ?

Comment: In "Test tt;" a default constructor for Test would be called (if it exists), but since you don't provide the code of Test this cannot be answered. Also, note that obj is not used at all, so the compiler might as well optimize it away.

Comment: write the code completely and show where you are printing.

Comment: @DanielDaranas , could you please tell me now that why constructor is not being call for Test obj and return tt.

Comment: @RazibHossainShuvo. No. I refuse to analyze code such as that. Sorry, but it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an instance of a class by value invokes the copy constructor.

The compiler implements the copy constructor by default (essentially a memberwise copy after invoking copy constructors of any base classes) if the class definition does not explicitly supply one.   This compiler-generated copy constructor will not call one of the other constructors you have implemented, so constructing the copy will not print anything.   However, the destructor will be invoked to clean up the copy when done.

Within your class, if you implement a copy constructor as follows;

```
Test(const Test &from) : x(from.x)
{
    std::cout << "Copy constructor invoked" << std::endl;
}
```

you will find that the copy constructor is indeed being invoked.